# Uploading and displaying an image from Computer in to a FLUTTER WEB APP during runtime

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to upload an image via a FLUTTER WEB app from my computer internal folder (macos) and truing to display the same image in the same FLUTTER WEB app. Both uploading and displaying is done during run time of the app.

I am getting the following exception. How do I fix this issue?

Thank you.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Expected a value of type 'Widget?', but got one of type 'DecorationImage'
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ImageUploader(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageUploader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageUploaderState createState() => _ImageUploaderState();
}

class _ImageUploaderState extends State<ImageUploader> {
  Uint8List imagevalue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
              child: Text(
                'Mah Links',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Karla',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                child: imagevalue == null
                    ? Text('No Image')
                    : DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: Image.memory(imagevalue).image)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        heroTag: 'picker',
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent[400],
        hoverElevation: 0,
        label: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.file_upload),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text('Upload Image')
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () => uploadImage(),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  uploadImage() {
    // HTML input element
    InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.click();

    uploadInput.onChange.listen(
      (changeEvent) {
        final file = uploadInput.files.first;
        final reader = FileReader();
        // The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the
        // contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer,
        // using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.
        // Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

        reader.readAsDataUrl(file);

        String imgString = reader.result; //.toString();
        Uint8List base64string = Base64Decoder().convert(imgString);

        reader.onLoadEnd.listen(
          (loadEndEvent) async {
            setState(() {
              imagevalue = base64string;
            });
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to pick an image from the computer internal directory from a flutter web app during runtime:

make sure to insert the `file_picker` package into pubspec.yaml

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ImageUploader(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageUploader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageUploaderState createState() => _ImageUploaderState();
}

class _ImageUploaderState extends State<ImageUploader> {
  Uint8List imagevalue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
              child: Text(
                'Mah Links',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Karla',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                child: imagevalue == null
                    ? Text('No Image')
                    : Image.memory(imagevalue))
            // : DecorationImage(
            //     fit: BoxFit.cover,
            //     image: Image.memory(imagevalue).image)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        heroTag: 'picker',
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent[400],
        hoverElevation: 0,
        label: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.file_upload),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text('Upload Image')
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () => uploadImage(),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  uploadImage() async {
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'svg', 'jpeg']);

    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile file = result.files.first;

      setState(() {
        imagevalue = file.bytes;
      });

    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to make it work with null safety now?

Comment: @Apoorvpandey check latest version of file picker https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker